# How to display Android Fragments Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am writing an android app on android 3.1. I am showing 2 fragments side by side initially . When I select other tab I need to create 2 more fragments dynamically in order to replace the original fragments . I also need to set the width and weight of those new fragments dynamically.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [Nick Campion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223440/nick-campion) said.

Here's a code fragment that works for me:

```
    Fragment newFragment = MainFrag.newInstance(arg);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_container, newFragment).commit();
```

Note that I am using the support library for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to do this. `FragmentManager.beginTransaction();` then `add` and `remove` fragments as you please and finally call `commit`. It should be pretty straightforward if you look at that documentation.